# WebLogic config wizard dies

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm installing WebLogic 12.1.2 for development version on Ubuntu.  I went through all of the steps to unpack and run the configuration script to set up the environment.  When I go to execute MW_HOME/wlserver/common/bin/config.sh, the domain configuration wizard comes up for a few seconds, then dies.

I added echo on to this script and another one called in oracle_common

```
dev@dev-VirtualBox:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/common/bin$ ./config.sh
+ pwd
+ mypwd=/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/common/bin
+ SCRIPTNAME=./config.sh
+ dirname /usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/common/bin/./config.sh
+ SCRIPTPATH=/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/common/bin/.
+ cd /usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/common/bin/./../../..
+ pwd
+ MW_HOME=/usr/local/wls12120
+ export MW_HOME
+ /usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/common/bin/config.sh
+ pwd
+ mypwd=/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/common/bin
+ SCRIPTNAME=/usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/common/bin/config.sh
+ dirname /usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/common/bin/config.sh
+ SCRIPTPATH=/usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/common/bin
+ cd /usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/common/bin/../..
+ pwd
+ ORACLE_HOME=/usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common
+ export ORACLE_HOME
+ cd /usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/..
+ pwd
+ MW_HOME=/usr/local/wls12120
+ export MW_HOME
+ . /usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/common/bin/setHomeDirs.sh
+ WL_HOME=/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver
+ export WL_HOME
+ COMMON_COMPONENTS_HOME=/usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common
+ [ -d /usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common ]
+ cd /usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common
+ pwd
+ COMMON_COMPONENTS_HOME=/usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common
+ export COMMON_COMPONENTS_HOME
+ [ -z /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67 -o -z Oracle ]
+ export JAVA_HOME
+ uname -s
+ OS=Linux
+ umask 027
+ . /usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/common/bin/commEnv.sh
+ [ -z /usr/local/wls12120 -a -z /usr/local/wls12120/wlserver ]
+ [ ! -d /usr/local/wls12120 ]
+ [ ! -d /usr/local/wls12120/wlserver ]
+ BEA_HOME=/usr/local/wls12120
+ COHERENCE_HOME=/usr/local/wls12120/coherence
+ MODULES_DIR=/usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/modules
+ FEATURES_DIR=/usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/modules/features
+ ANT_HOME=/usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.1
+ [ -f /usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.1/lib/ant.jar ]
+ ANT_CONTRIB=/usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/modules/net.sf.antcontrib_1.1.0.0_1-0b2
+ [ false != true ]
+ JAVA_USE_64BIT=false
+ ENV_JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67
+ [ -z /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67 -o -z Oracle ]
+ JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre ]
+ JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre
+ export JRE_HOME
+ [ -z  ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/bin/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/alt-rt.jar/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/applet/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/calendars.properties/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/charsets.jar/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/classlist/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/cmm/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/content-types.properties/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/currency.data/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/deploy/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/deploy.jar/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/desktop/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/ext/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/flavormap.properties/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/fontconfig.RedHat.5.bfc/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/fontconfig.RedHat.5.properties.src/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/fontconfig.RedHat.6.bfc/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/fontconfig.RedHat.6.properties.src/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/fontconfig.SuSE.10.bfc/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/fontconfig.SuSE.10.properties.src/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/fontconfig.SuSE.11.bfc/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/fontconfig.SuSE.11.properties.src/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/fontconfig.Turbo.bfc/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/fontconfig.Turbo.properties.src/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/fontconfig.bfc/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/fontconfig.properties.src/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/fonts/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/i386/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/images/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/javafx.properties/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/javaws.jar/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/jce.jar/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/jexec/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/jfr/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/jfr.jar/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/jsse.jar/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/jvm.hprof.txt/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/locale/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/logging.properties/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/management/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/management-agent.jar/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/meta-index/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/net.properties/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/oblique-fonts/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/plugin.jar/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/psfont.properties.ja/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/psfontj2d.properties/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/resources.jar/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/rt.jar/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/security/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/sound.properties/jrockit ]
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/zi/jrockit ]
+ export BEA_HOME MW_HOME WL_HOME MODULES_DIR FEATURES_DIR COHERENCE_HOME ANT_HOME ANT_CONTRIB JAVA_HOME JAVA_VENDOR PRODUCTION_MODE JAVA_USE_64BIT VM_TYPE
+ uname -s
+ [ : =  ]
+ [ : =  ]
+ export PATHSEP CLASSPATHSEP
+ VERIFY_NONE=
+ [  = true ]
+ [  = JRockit ]
+ JAVA_VM=-client
+ MEM_ARGS=-Xms32m -Xmx200m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
+ VERIFY_NONE=-Xverify:none
+ JAVA_OPTIONS= -Xverify:none -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/endorsed:/usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/modules/endorsed -Xverify:none -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/endorsed:/usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/modules/endorsed
+ [  !=  ]
+ uname -s
+ export JAVA_VM MEM_ARGS JAVA_OPTIONS
+ [ -f /usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/common/bin/setPatchEnv.sh ]
+ uname -s
+ uname -m
+ arch=i686
+ [ -n :/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/native/linux/i686:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/native/linux/i686/oci920_8 ]
+ [ i686 = ia64 ]
+ [ i686 = x86_64 -a false = true ]
+ [ i686 = s390x ]
+ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/native/linux/i686:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/native/linux/i686/oci920_8:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/native/linux/i686:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/native/linux/i686/oci920_8
+ [  = true ]
+ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=::/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/native/linux/i686:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/native/linux/i686/oci920_8:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/native/linux/i686:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/native/linux/i686/oci920_8
+ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
+ SYSTEM_LOADER=SystemClassLoader
+ LAUNCH_COMPLETE=weblogic.store.internal.LockManagerImpl
+ PCL_JAR=/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/lib/pcl2.jar
+ PROFILE_CLASSPATH=/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic_sp.jar:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/lib/webservices.jar
+ echo
+ awk {print toupper($0)}
+ SERVER_PROFILE=
+ [  = WEB ]
+ export PROFILE_CLASSPATH
+ CAM_NODEMANAGER_JAR_PATH=/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/modules/features/oracle.wls.common.nodemanager_1.0.0.0.jar
+ [ ! -f /usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/modules/features/oracle.wls.common.nodemanager_1.0.0.0.jar ]
+ export CAM_NODEMANAGER_JAR_PATH
+ WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/lib/tools.jar:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic_sp.jar:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/lib/webservices.jar:/usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.1/lib/ant-all.jar:/usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/modules/net.sf.antcontrib_1.1.0.0_1-0b2/lib/ant-contrib.jar:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/modules/features/oracle.wls.common.nodemanager_1.0.0.0.jar
+ uname -s
+ export WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH
+ FMWCONFIG_CLASSPATH=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/lib/tools.jar:/usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/common/lib/config-launch.jar:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic_sp.jar:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/lib/webservices.jar:/usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.1/lib/ant-all.jar:/usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/modules/net.sf.antcontrib_1.1.0.0_1-0b2/lib/ant-contrib.jar
+ FMWLAUNCH_CLASSPATH=/usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/common/lib/config-launch.jar
+ [ ! -z  ]
+ export FMWCONFIG_CLASSPATH FMWLAUNCH_CLASSPATH
+ [  !=  ]
+ [  = true ]
+ DERBY_HOME=/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/common/derby
+ DERBY_CLIENT_CLASSPATH=/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/common/derby/lib/derbyclient.jar:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/common/derby/lib/derby.jar
+ DERBY_CLASSPATH=:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/common/derby/lib/derbynet.jar:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/common/derby/lib/derbyclient.jar:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/common/derby/lib/derby.jar
+ DERBY_TOOLS=/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/common/derby/lib/derbytools.jar
+ DERBY_SYSTEM_HOME=/common/db
+ DERBY_OPTS=-Dderby.system.home=/common/db
+ [  !=  ]
+ [  !=  ]
+ export DERBY_HOME DERBY_CLASSPATH DERBY_TOOLS DERBY_SYSTEM_HOME DERBY_OPTS
+ uname -s
+ [ Linux = CYGWIN32/NT ]
+ + uname -s
grep -i cygwin_
+ [ -n  ]
+ PATH=/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/bin:/usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.1/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/bin:/usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.1/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/dev/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin:/usr/local/eclipse:/usr/local/node-v0.10.32-linux-x86/bin:/usr/local/mongodb-linux-i686-2.6.4/bin:/usr/local/robomongo-0.8.4-i386/bin:/usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/modules/org.apache.maven_3.0.4/bin
+ + uname -sgrep -i windows_nt

+ [ -n  ]
+ export PATH
+ resetFd
+ uname -s
+ grep -i cygwin
+ grep -i windows_nt
+ uname -s
+ uname -s
+ grep -i HP-UX
+ [ ! -n  ]
+ ulimit -S -n
+ ofiles=1024
+ ulimit -H -n
+ maxfiles=4096
+ expr 4096 : [0-9][0-9]*$
+ expr 1024 : [0-9][0-9]*$
+ [ 0 = 0 -a 4 -eq 0 -a 4 -eq 0 ]
+ uname -s
+ expr 4096 : [0-9][0-9]*$
+ [ 1 = 0 -a Linux = SunOS -a 4 -eq 0 ]
+ CLASSPATHSEP=:
+ export CLASSPATHSEP
+ CLASSPATH=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/lib/tools.jar:/usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/common/lib/config-launch.jar:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic_sp.jar:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/server/lib/webservices.jar:/usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.1/lib/ant-all.jar:/usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/modules/net.sf.antcontrib_1.1.0.0_1-0b2/lib/ant-contrib.jar::/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/common/derby/lib/derbynet.jar:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/common/derby/lib/derbyclient.jar:/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/common/derby/lib/derby.jar
+ export CLASSPATH
+ [ 0 -gt 0 ]
+ [ -z  ]
+ [ 0 -gt 0 ]
+ export ARGUMENTS
+ cd /usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/common/lib
+ [ -f /usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common/common/bin/cam_config.sh ]
+ JVM_ARGS=-Dprod.props.file='/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/.product.properties' -DCOMMON_COMPONENTS_HOME='/usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common' -Dpython.cachedir=/tmp/cachedir  -Xms32m -Xmx200m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m 
+ [ -d /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67 ]
+ eval "${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java" -Dprod.props.file='/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/.product.properties' -DCOMMON_COMPONENTS_HOME='/usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common' -Dpython.cachedir=/tmp/cachedir -Xms32m -Xmx200m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m com.oracle.cie.wizard.WizardController
+ /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java -Dprod.props.file=/usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/.product.properties -DCOMMON_COMPONENTS_HOME=/usr/local/wls12120/oracle_common -Dpython.cachedir=/tmp/cachedir -Xms32m -Xmx200m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m com.oracle.cie.wizard.WizardController
+ returnCode=255
+ cd /usr/local/wls12120/wlserver/common/bin
+ exit 255
```

Answer (score 0):

I  installed weblogic 12.1.2 to ubuntu after executing config.sh. i can only guess about your situation from this question. I hope you haven't just console because config.sh opens gui. Also process is so slow that i created two domains. I waited so long and assumed that process is dead then executed config.sh again. After i checked the processes and saw that they ar still alive. In short way just wait :)

Answer (score 0):

To start config.sh in console "text" mode, use

> config.sh -mode=console

If you want a log file, use

> config.sh -mode=console -log=/tmp/wl_config_sh.log